# « cœurs aimants » ou « cœurs aimant »

Tags: accord, participe-présent

Dans la phrase :

> Ces gens-là sont des cœurs aimant(s).

Doit-on accorder « aimants » comme adjectif du nom « cœurs » ? Ou bien « aimant » est-il participe présent invariable ?

Comment: On parle ici de coeurs qui aiment ou de coeurs ferromagnétiques ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le participe présent s'accorde lorsqu'il est utilisé comme adjectif, mais pas lorsqu'il est utilisé comme verbe. De plus, pour certains verbes, l'adjectif a une orthographe différente : *différant/différent*, *convainquant/convaincant*, *sachant/savant*, *pouvant/puissant*... En soi cette explication n'est pas suffisante puisque un participe présent peut avoir une *fonction* d'adjectif (c'est-à-dire que son rôle dans la phrase est celui d'un adjectif), même s'il n'a pas la *nature* d'adjectif mais celle d'un verbe (c'est-à-dire que le mot en lui-même n'est pas formé comme un adjectif : il est formé comme un verbe, et se conjugue comme un verbe).

Pour savoir de quel cas il s'agit, on peut commencer par chercher des indications sûres.

1. « En » + participe présent est invariable.

   > Ces gens-là ont des cœurs qui se plaisent **en** aim**ant**.   (gérondif ⇒ invariable)
2. Si le participe présent a un complément d'objet direct, un complément d'objet indirect ou un complément circonstanciel, c'est forcément un verbe.

   > Ces gens-là ont des cœurs aim**ant l'aventure**.   (COD ⇒ verbe ⇒ pas d'accord)

   > Ces gens-là ont des cœurs aim**ant à flâner**.   (COI ⇒ verbe ⇒ pas d'accord)

   > Ces gens-là ont des cœurs aim**ant pour la vie**.   (CC ⇒ verbe ⇒ pas d'accord)
3. Quelques participes présents ne peuvent pas être utilisés comme adjectifs. C'est une règle presque sûre, mais très marginale.

   > <sup>?</sup>Je vois des gens pensant, réfléchissant.   (« Réfléchissant » ne peut être utilisé comme adjectif que dans le sens de « reflétant la lumière » et pas dans le sens de « pensant ». Mais on dirait plutôt « je vois des gens qui pensent, qui réfléchissent ».)

   (Attention, en philosophie, il n'est pas rare d'utiliser un participe présent comme nom et de là comme adjectif. Un philosophe qui parle de « personnes pouvantes » sait ce qu'il dit, mais ce n'est pas du français standard.)

Un adjectif et une proposition réduite à un verbe au participe présent peuvent tous les deux être des compléments d'un nom. Mais la plupart du temps, s'il n'y a pas de raison qui fasse qu'il s'agisse d'un verbe, alors il s'agit d'un adjectif, qui s'accorde avec le nom qu'il qualifie. C'est a priori le cas ici.

> Ces gens-là sont des **cœurs** aim**ants**.   (épithète de *cœurs*)

> Les **cœurs** que sont ces gens-là sont aim**ants**.   (attribut du sujet *cœurs*)

Grammaticalement, on pourrait analyser *aimant* comme une proposition subordonnées, mais je ne vois pas quel sens cela aurait : le verbe *aimer* a normalement besoin d'un complément. Le complément peut être implicite, mais il faudrait un contexte qui le rende évident.

En règle générale, un participe présent utilisé comme un adjectif dénote un état, alors qu'un participe présent utilisé comme verbe dénote une action. Je crois que c'est la règle déterminante, mais elle a un intérêt pratique limité parce que la frontière entre action et état peut être floue.

> Je vois des **électrices** vot**ant**.   (Je les vois en train de voter : c'est une action.)
> Ce sondage sur les attentes envers la classe politique en matière de violences contre les femmes a été réalisé auprès d'**électrices** vot**antes**.   (Il s'agit de personnes qui ont participé à un scrutin. Sans accorder *votant*, la phrase signifierait qu'on leur a posé des questions pendant qu'elles mettaient leur bulletin dans l'urne.)

Quelques références (dont j'ai tiré certains exemples) :

- [Blog de Jean-Christophe Pellat chez Grevisse — Participe présent et adjectif verbal : comment les distinguer ?*](https://www.grevisse.fr/le-blog-chroniques-grevisse/grammaire/participe-present-et-adjectif-verbal-comment-les-distinguer)
- [Banque de dépannage linguistique — Participe présent et adjectif verbal](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2915)
- [Assistance scolaire personnalisée — Distinguer le participe présent et l'adjectif verbal](https://www.assistancescolaire.com/eleve/3e/francais/reviser-une-notion/distinguer-le-participe-present-et-l-adjectif-verbal-3_fra_37)
- [Espace français — Le participe présent, l'adjectif verbal et le gérondif](https://www.espacefrancais.com/le-participe-present-ladjectif-verbal-et-le-gerondif/)
- [Français facile — Adjectif verbal ou participe présent](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-35237.php)

---

Pour quelqu'un qui parle le français couramment, on peut faire le test du féminin : est-ce que l'accord au féminin, qui se prononce toujours différemment dans ce cas, sonne bien ?

> *<strike>Ces gens-là sont des **têtes aimants**.</strike>   (ça ne sonne pas bien)
> Ces gens-là sont des **têtes aimantes**.   (pas de problème)

Comment: Il me semble qu'un subjonctif serait préférable: « …s'il n'y a pas de raison qui fasse qu'il s'agisse…». (action non accomplies).

Comment: Le "test du féminin" :
Les années passant --> sonne bien
Les années passantes --> sonne mal
Donc j'écrirais : Les siècles passant.

Comment: @BertrandHerrmann Oui : « Les années passant, il vieillit » = « Comme les années passent, il vieillit » (verbe) ≠ « Les rues habituellement passantes sont désertes aujourd'hui » = « Les rues où beaucoup de gens passent d'habitude sont désertes aujourd'hui » (adjectif).